# Safari on Windows - text does not appear normal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, text, safari

The heading and text in footer section do not appear normal, they are sort of cut off (and disappear) and become normal once they are selected. The code is a bit long. If you are familiar with safari on windows please have a look:

Image:
[image: abnormal text on safari footer]

[image]

Links: 
Home: http://timekill.in/extenso_safari/ 
CSS: http://timekill.in/extenso_safari/css/theme.css

the site is built on bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

A faster solution is to use Google Fonts (since you are using PT Sans, and this collection [are available there](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/PT+Sans)).

You need to add to your HTML head:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And change your line 157 of `theme.css` to:

```
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
```

I have tested using your same code and it works on Safari 5 on Windows!